# фотоальбом для сайта. Условия JS скрипта

Tags: javascript, условия, веб-сайт

Вопрос в JS. Это фотоальбом. Сверху большая картинка, снизу маленькие. Если кликнуть на маленькую картинку, она выбирается, всё верно, но картинка не меняется на большую, потому что они работают на разных системах. Первая система через function "prev", "next" а вторая система через "var images". Как я понимаю, нужно сделать через else,if условия, тогда будет работать система, но к сожалению я сделал всё что мог, и никак.

Вот ссылка на весь проект: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/QPny/yV6Gho43g

```
<body>
<div class="ts1">
<div class="img-box">
    <img id="0" class="sliderimg" src="" alt="preview" /><br/>
    <img id="1" class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this);" src="img/jac/a.jpg" alt="1" />
    <img id="2" class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this);" src="img/jac/b.jpg" alt="2" />
    <img id="3" class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this);" src="img/jac/c.jpg" alt="3" />
    <img id="4" class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this);" src="img/jac/d.jpg" alt="4" />
    <img id="5" class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this);" src="img/jac/e.jpg" alt="5" />
            <button class="btnneev prev" onclick="prev()"><</button>
            <button class="btnneev next" onclick="next()">></button>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    var i = 1;
    var slider_img = document.querySelector('.sliderimg');
    var images = ['jac/a.jpg', 'jac/b.jpg', 'jac/c.jpg', 'jac/d.jpg', 'jac/e.jpg']; /* вторая система */

    document.getElementById(0).images = document.getElementById(i).images;
    document.getElementById(i).className = "thumb selected"; 
    function preview(img) {document.getElementById(i).className = "thumb normal";
    img.className = "thumb selected"; 
    document.getElementById(0).images = img.images;
    i = img.id;
}

    function prev(){ /* первая система */
    if(i <= 0) i = images.length;   
    i--;
    return setImg();             
}

    function next(){ /* первая система */
    if(i >= images.length-1) i = -1;
    i++;
    return setImg();             
}

    function setImg(){
    return slider_img.setAttribute('src', "img/"+images[i]); 
}


</script>

</body>
```

[image: альбом]

Answer (score 1):

Решение любой проблемы следует начать с определения этой проблемы. Важно быть аккуратным и точным.

> Если кликнуть на маленькую картинку, она выбирается, всё верно, но картинка не меняется на большую

Отбросим лишнее. Если что-то верно, то не стоит об этом и беспокоится. Вот что получим:

> Если кликнуть на маленькую картинку, картинка не меняется на большую

Теперь вспомним про аккуратность и точность:

> Если кликнуть на маленькую картинку, то большая картинка не меняется на соответствующую маленькой

Совсем другой смысл! Верно?

Теперь попробуйте описать своими словами, что происходит в вашем коде. Будьте проще, не надо вводить малопонятные абстракции типа "система". Я вам помогу:

При клике на маленькую картинку вызывается функция `preview`:

1. снимаем выделение с ранее выбранной маленькой картинки: её класс = `thumb normal`;
2. выделяем текущую маленькую картинку: её класс = `thumb selected`;
3. свойство `images` большой картинки = свойству `images` текущей маленькой картинки;
4. предыдущая маленькая картинка = текущая маленькая картинка (чтобы в следующий раз можно было снять с неё выделение).

Шаги 1, 2 и 4 понятны. А что насчёт шага 3? Что это за свойство `images` у большой картинки? Заглянем в [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement). Хммм Никаких images. Может быть ошибка тут? Если посмотреть на код, который меняет большую картинку (функция `setImg`), то там изменяется атрибут `src`, а не `images`. Дело раскрыто.

Вот так, внимательно и последовательно анализируя проблему и код, можно решить практически любую задачу в программировании.